# Why does calling to_i on a Float subtract one from the value?

Tags: ruby, floating-point-precision

I have a case where I am doing some math on a Float object and when I call to_i on it it is being reduced by one.

```
value = 0.29 * 100
value.to_i
=> 28
```

I know that floating point numbers are inexact representations but this is off by more than I would expect.  What is going on and how can I prevent this?

I'm using ruby 1.8.7 (it also happens in 1.8.6).

Comment: When will people understand floating point values loose precision when converted to integers?

Comment: In this case you might want to use `value.ceil`

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I was expecting 29 as the result.

Answer (score 6):

```
(0.29 * 100).round
 => 29
```

Not all floating point numbers are inexact. `29` is exact, `0.25` is exact, but `0.29` is not. If even one bit is missing 50 bits to the right of the decimal point, the default truncating conversion will return the next lower integer.

And that's why `#round` exists.

Answer (score 3):

A quick check in irb reveals that `0.29 * 100` evaluates to `28.999...`. Calling `Float#to_i` does the rest and you end up with 28.

Comment: How do you see that it evaluates to `28.999...`?

Comment: You fire up irb, you enter `0.29 * 100`, you hit enter and it tells you the value of the expression.

Comment: I do that and I get `29.0` not `28.999...` hence why I would think to_i would return 29.

Comment: Hm, try using `"%.20f" % (0.29 * 100)` instead then. It's possible that it is rounding the value for output in some versions when using plain `Float#inspect`

Comment: Ahh... That produced `28.99999999999999644729`.